# NullPointerException in android 4.3, on back navigation from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a mainActivity with several list fragments say A,B,C and D. Navigation of these fragments within main activity is A->B->C->D.

From the fragment D new detailsActivity is started. While on the detailsActivity when I press back button, I should go back to the mainActivity with selected fragments.

This is working fine in all versions of android except android 4.3. I get following NullPointerException. The difference I observed that in android 4.3 on back navigation onCreate method is called on the mainActivity, this is not happening in pervious versions of andriod. I am unable to find workaround, Please help!!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.main/com.app.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setListAdapter(ListFragment.java:182)
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:365)
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
```

Comment: We need to take a look at some of your code. Do you use ViewPagers? Do you use SaveInstanceState? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens in ArrayAdapter.getCount during ListFragment initialization, and the exception is a NullPointerException.  That means that the adapter backing your ListView is being initialized with a null `List<T>` object.  You should look at where you're calling `setListAdapter` and where you're initializing the List that you pass into it.  You need to ensure that your List has been initialized first.

If you want more specific recommendations, post your ListFragment code.